# Flyway failed to initialize. Doesn't see files

Tags: database, postgresql, jpa, migration, flyway

I have error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-02-11 19:25:22.908 ERROR 8116 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Flyway failed to initialize: none of the following migration scripts locations could be found:

    - classpath:db/migration


Action:

Review the locations above or check your Flyway configuration
```

**But the folder and files with scripts exist!**

[image]

Also:

```
Appication.properties

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

Why doesn't Flyway see the files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something is not right. Based on the image icon your folder is a package, not a resource folder. Maybe your directory name is `db.migration` not `db/migration`? Create the folder again using terminal or file manager.

Comment: The only difference btw the db.migration and `> db > migration` in  the folder structure in IntelliJ is a setting on the Project config.

Tree Appearance > Compact Middle Packages

packages are folders anyway